# Why does not work custom options in Angular JS Dropdown Multiselect?

Tags: angularjs, drop-down-menu

I use plugin [Angular JS Dropdown Multiselect](http://dotansimha.github.io/angularjs-dropdown-multiselect/#/)

I can to set custom options for dropdown using property `extra-settings`:

```
$scope.categorysettings = {
   smartButtonMaxItems: 1,
   selectionLimit: 5,
   enableSearch: true
};
```

In this object I set option `enableSearch: true`. It means that dropdown multipox has search field.

**HTML:**

```
<div ng-dropdown-multiselect="" options="specializationSelect" selected-model="specialization" extra-settings="categorysettings" translation-texts="example5customTexts" checkboxes="true"></div>
```

So, I get result HTML dropdown without search field however I set custom options.

Comment: You should ask the question from the plugin development team.

Comment: I think you didn't add the html section.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I added, problem is resolved. Instead

`extra-settings="categorysettings"`

I use object directly in template:

`extra-settings="{selectionLimit: 5}"`